# ¿Cómo logro que SUM() sólo cuente los pasajeros seleccionados por MIN()?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una duda respecto a SQL Server. Estoy intentando hacer una consulta que me regrese a las dos aerolíneas con menor número de vuelos, además de la cantidad de pasajeros que han tenido en total los vuelos (no cada uno, sino en general de cada aerolínea). Abajo adjunto tanto las tablas como el código que he estado modificando e intentando corregir: este me regresa los dos con menor número de vuelos, el problema sigue siendo la suma.

AEROLINEAS

[image: R]

VUELOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CIUDADES

[image: L]

Mi código, el cual sólo me regresa la suma total de todos los pasajeros:

```
SELECT A.Nombre, MINIMO.[# de Vuelos] AS 'Num. de Vuelos'
FROM AEROLINEAS A,
     (SELECT MIN(V.Total) AS '# de Vuelos' FROM 
        (SELECT Aerolinea, COUNT(Aerolinea) AS 'Total' FROM VUELOS GROUP BY Aerolinea) V,
        AEROLINEAS A
    WHERE A.IdAerolinea = V.Aerolinea) MINIMO,
    (SELECT Aerolinea, COUNT(Aerolinea) AS 'Total' FROM VUELOS GROUP BY Aerolinea) TOTAL
WHERE TOTAL.Total = MINIMO.[# de Vuelos] AND A.IdAerolinea = TOTAL.Aerolinea
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una tabla de expresión común para los datos que quieres obtener. Cuando los tienes agrupados, puedes utilizar Row_number sobre el Número de vuelos y obtener del conjunto, las dos primeras filas.

```
Create table Aerolineas
             (
             idAeroLinea int
           , Nombre      varchar(100)
             );

Create table Vuelos
             (
             NumVuelo      int
           , Fecha         date
           , Origen        int
           , Destino       int
           , Aerolinea     int
           , NumPasajeros  int
           , Internacional bit
             );

Create table Ciudades
             (
             idCiudad int
           , Ciudad   varchar(100)
             );
go
Insert into Ciudades (idCiudad, Ciudad)
values
(1,'Chicago'),
(2,'New York'),
(3,'Paris'),
(4,'Madrid'),
(5,'Houston');
go
Insert into Aerolineas (idAeroLinea, Nombre)
values
(1,'Delta'),
(2,'United'),
(3,'Air France');
go
Insert into Vuelos (NumVuelo, Fecha, Origen, Destino, Aerolinea, NumPasajeros, Internacional)
values
(44 ,'20140208',2,3,3,135,1),
(76 ,'20140317',2,1,2,80 ,0),
(380,'20140604',5,1,2,147,0),
(421,'20140421',1,2,1,185,0),
(572,'20140912',5,4,3,99 ,1),
(906,'20140510',3,2,3,154,1),
(918,'20141224',1,5,1,122,0);
go

 With R as (
    SELECT A.Nombre
         , COUNT(V.NumVuelo) AS [Num. de Vuelos]
         , SUM(V.NumPasajeros) as [Total]
           FROM AEROLINEAS AS A
                     INNER JOIN Vuelos AS V ON A.idAeroLinea = V.Aerolinea
           GROUP BY A.Nombre
           ), numeradas as (
           Select * 
           , ROW_NUMBER() over(order by r.[Num. de Vuelos]) as row
           from r
           )
           Select n.Nombre, n.[Num. de Vuelos], n.Total
           from numeradas n
           Where row < 3
```

[image: Resultados]

[Tablas de expresión común correlativas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-2-correlativos/)

[Row number](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/11/row-number-numerar-filas/)

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. El problema es que no se me permite usar el valor explícito, así que no sé si de igual manera podría realizarse con el procedimiento que usted dice.

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir, con no se me permite usar el valor explícito?. En la query que le traslado, no existe ningún valor explícito, salvo el número que índica de dos aerolíneas. Se puede sustituir por una variable. Quizá sino, puedas mejorar el enunciado, y así obtendremos mejores resultados.